# End to End Encryption in firebase android application

Tags: android, firebase, encryption, aes, public-key-encryption

I have an firebase application which consist of group chats.
and I want to implement end-to-end encryption.
So far I've tried to below strategy to

1) Create an secret key (AES) for group to encrypt/decrypt texts

2) Created RSA key for individual users

3) encrypting AES secret key using user's public RSA key and decrypting using private key

I want to keep the AES key on server by encryting and then, allow user to fetch that AES key thru API and use to encrypt/decrypt messages

AESKEY (encrypted) ---> (decrypt to plain text(this is the challenge - how to decrypt this on server side) ----> encrypt using public key of user) ----> send to user

The challenge I am facing is, as I have encrypted the AESKEY on Server using my public key, but when the user requests the AESKEY, my application may be offline so eventually the user will not get the decrypted AESKEY

I was thinking to keep AESKEY on server by encrypting and on user's request I perform encryption/decryption task on server itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite unreasonable to do this, as it's a lot simpler and not less safe to only encrypt the message itself with the other parties' public key, and then they can all decrypt it themselves with their private keys.